# ASP.NET C# image file not get in folder

Tags: asp.net

```
string filename = bupload.PostedFile.FileName;   //upload pdf file
PdfDocument pdf = new PdfDocument();
pdf.LoadFromFile(filename);
System.Drawing.Image img = System.Drawing.Image.FromFile("watermark.jpg");// upload image
pdf.Pages[0].BackgroundImage = img;
pdf.SaveToFile("watermark.pdf");
```

how can add watermark  and save a file in particular folder in my website and no change he name of file file name is same as uploaded file name

Comment: you are saving the file with `watermark.pdf` name right?

Comment: you can use `Server.MapPath("~/foldername");` will give you the physical address of the folder. Add filename in that and save it.

Comment: Thank-you But its not work

Comment: Yes watermark.pdf but  some exception is genrate is file does not exist parameter :filename

Comment: string filename = noteupload1.PostedFile.FileName;
                PdfDocument pdffile = new PdfDocument();
                pdffile.LoadFromFile(filename);
                PdfPageBase page = pdffile.Pages[0];
                System.Drawing.Image image = System.Drawing.Image.FromFile("E:\\CollEGEp\\CollegeProject\\watermark\\watermark.jpg");
                page.BackgroundImage=image;
                pdffile.SaveToFile(Server.MapPath("~/NoteFile/"+filename));this is code sir but not add watermark in pdf file  exception is generated is file does not exist parametername:filename